# Correct way to handle conditional styling in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing some React right now and I was wondering if there is a "correct" way to do conditional styling. In the tutorial they use

```
style={{
  textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
}}
```

I prefer not to use inline styling so I want to instead use a class to control conditional styling. How would one approach this in the React way of thinking? Or should I just use this inline styling way?

Comment: I think you might have `redux` and `react` confused. Redux has nothing to do with styling.

Comment: i think your preference is spot-on for documents, but over-zealous for applications where markup interchange compat is not important. some major web apps are actually getting rid of classes and using only inline style, which is more predictable and easier to reason about than which of 5 applied rules is making the text bold. when the attribs are dynamic, you don't save much bandwidth like you do with repetitive documents. the app's semantics (view-source markup) are not that important either...

Comment: @rossipedia ah yes thank you, got mixed up, was looking at the redux tutorial when thinking about this, thank you!

Comment: If you aren't sure what the value of text-decoration will be because of the cascade and you only want to apply a line-through if complete is true, you'll have to build a style object. This way, you don't set it to none accidentally when it was another value.

const style = {

}

if (complete) {
  style['textDecoration'] = 'line-through'
}

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If you prefer to use a class name, by all means use a class name.

```
className={completed ? 'text-strike' : null}
```

You may also find the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package helpful. With it, your code would look like this:

```
className={classNames({ 'text-strike': completed })}
```

There's no "correct" way to do conditional styling. Do whatever works best for you. For myself, I prefer to avoid inline styling and use classes in the manner just described.

**POSTSCRIPT [06-AUG-2019]**

Whilst it remains true that React is unopinionated about styling, these days I would recommend a CSS-in-JS solution; namely [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/) or [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction). If you're new to React, stick to CSS classes or inline styles to begin with. But once you're comfortable with React I recommend adopting one of these libraries. I use them in every project.

Comment: Hey there, if you decided to use className as your conditional styling method. Without the `classNames lib`. I  advise you to use `undefined` instead of `null`. The `className` property takes as input type a String or undefined - type(String | undefined) -- ⚡️

Comment: @JadRizk even better approach is to not set className at all if you don't have a valid value to set it to. `const attrs = completed?{className:'text-strike'}:{}` then `<li {...attrs}>text to maybe strike</li>` (spread operator). That way you don't set className at all unless you have a good value to assign. This is an important approach for setting some inline styles where you can't know what the current value is (because it could be set by CSS in a file you may not control).

Comment: @LinuxDisciple if all the fields evaluate to falsey then `classnames` just returns an empty string. This will not be affected by any CSS.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh 21 hours ago I thought JadRizk's solution was a false choice between `null` and `undefined` that would still result in a no-value `class` attribute in the html (i.e. `<p class></p>` instead of `<p></p>`) so I provided a method that avoided setting `className` at all. As it happens I was wrong about JadRizk's solution. For the stated problem, I believe your solution with JadRizk's refinement is best. My syntax can set an arbitrary list of props and their values conditionally, but it's overkill for just setting a class name.

Comment: "There's no "correct" way to do conditional styling. Do whatever works best for you. " Thank you, ive been banging my head against the wall trying to find "best practices"

Answer (score 197):

```
 <div style={{ visibility: this.state.driverDetails.firstName != undefined? 'visible': 'hidden'}}></div>
```

Checkout the above code. That will do the trick.

Comment: <div style={{ visibility: this.state.driverDetails.firstName !== undefined? 'visible': 'hidden'}}></div>. Small typo in ==.

Comment: Isn't this just the exact same method as posted in the question?

Answer (score 119):

If you need to conditionally apply inline styles (apply all or nothing) then this notation also works:

```
style={ someCondition ? { textAlign:'center', paddingTop: '50%'} : {}}
```

In case 'someCondition' not fulfilled then you pass empty object.

Comment: Doesn't this pattern create an unnecessary diff though? My understanding of DOM diffing is that the `style` prop here would always change since in Javascript `{} != {}`

If I'm correct about the diffing, perhaps it's better to use "`undefined`" instead of "`{}`"

Comment: Good note. I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 21):

instead of this:

```
style={{
  textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
}}
```

you could try the following using short circuiting:

```
style={{
  textDecoration: completed && 'line-through'
}}
```

https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb

key bit of information from the link:

*Short circuiting means that in JavaScript when we are evaluating an AND expression (&&), if the first operand is false, JavaScript will short-circuit and not even look at the second operand.*

It's worth noting that this would return false if the first operand is false, so might have to consider how this would affect your style.

The other solutions might be more best practice, but thought it would be worth sharing.

Comment: Using short circuit syntax will leave a empty "style" in the markup depending on the condition. I was searching to see if there are any known bugs caused by this and my search led me here. Do you see a problem with it?

Answer (score 17):

Another way, using inline style and the spread operator

```
style={{
  ...completed ? { textDecoration: completed } : {}
}}
```

That way be useful in some situations where you want to add a bunch of properties at the same time base on the condition.

Comment: Nice approach if you don't want to change a default style

Comment: I'd like to add 1 variant here: ...completed && { textDecoration: completed }

Comment: this solution is elegant and simple

Answer (score 17):

## inline style handling

```
style={{backgroundColor: selected ? 'red':'green'}}
```

## using Css

in js

```
className={`section ${selected && 'section_selected'}`}
```

in css

```
.section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
} 
.section_selected{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-width: 3px !important;
}
```

same can be done with Js stylesheets

Answer (score 8):

First, I agree with you as a matter of style - I would also (and do also) conditionally apply classes rather than inline styles. But you can use the same technique:

```
<div className={{completed ? "completed" : ""}}></div>
```

For more complex sets of state, accumulate an array of classes and apply them:

```
var classes = [];

if (completed) classes.push("completed");
if (foo) classes.push("foo");
if (someComplicatedCondition) classes.push("bar");

return <div className={{classes.join(" ")}}></div>;
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorted way to apply inline styling on some condition.

```
style={areFieldsDisabled ? {opacity: 0.5} : '' }
```

Comment: when areFieldsDisabled is false, you will get a code exception.

Comment: Then we need to use ternary operator.

Answer (score 4):

If you want assign styles based on condition, its better you use a class name for styles. For this assignment, there are different ways. These are two of them.

1.

```
    <div className={`another-class ${condition ? 'active' : ''}`} />
```

2. 

```
    <div className={`another-class ${condition && 'active'}`} />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you **do not** want to overwrite the original style, you can use empty styling with `{}`.

For instance, assigning a **background-color**, when you need to keep the initial color if the condition is not met.

```js
style={ onError ? {backgroundColor: 'red'} : {} }
// Will not overwrite the background color if the error does not occur.
```

```js
style={ completed ? {textDecoration: 'line-through'} : {} }
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question while trying to answer the same question. McCrohan's approach with the classes array & join is solid.

Through my experience, I have been working with a lot of legacy ruby code that is being converted to React and as we build the component(s) up I find myself reaching out for both existing css classes and inline styles.

example snippet inside a component:

```
// if failed, progress bar is red, otherwise green 
<div
    className={`progress-bar ${failed ? 'failed' : ''}`}
    style={{ width: this.getPercentage() }} 
/>
```

Again, I find myself reaching out to legacy css code, "packaging" it with the component and moving on.

So, I really feel that it is a bit in the air as to what is "best" as that label will vary greatly depending on your project.

Comment: You should not combine classNames with style attribute, that's bit of a mess

Comment: also btw - the second failed only has one single quote on the right...it needs to be either:  ${failed ? 'failed' : ''} or ${failed ? failed : ''}, not ${failed ? failed' : ''}

Answer (score 3):

```
 style={{
              whiteSpace: "unset",
              wordBreak: "break-all",
              backgroundColor: one.read == false && "#e1f4f3",
              borderBottom:'0.8px solid #fefefe'
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle styling is by using classes with set of css properties.

**example:**

```js
<Component className={this.getColor()} />

getColor() {
    let class = "badge m2";
    class += this.state.count===0 ? "warning" : danger;
    return class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like this.

```
render () {
    var btnClass = 'btn';
    if (this.state.isPressed) btnClass += ' btn-pressed';
    else if (this.state.isHovered) btnClass += ' btn-over';
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
```

Or  else, you can use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames#usage-with-reactjs) NPM package to make dynamic and conditional className props simpler to work with (especially more so than conditional string manipulation).

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar'
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar'
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => ''
classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
classNames({ foo: true, bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone uses `Typescript` (which does not except `null` values for style) and wants to use react styling, I would suggest this hack:

```js
<p 
style={choiceStyle ? styles.choiceIsMade : styles.none}>
{question}
</p>

const styles = {
choiceIsMade: {...},
 none: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change Inline CSS Conditionally Based on Component State.**

This is also the Correct way to handle conditional styling in React.

> condition ? expressionIfTrue : expressionIfFalse;

example =>

```
{this.state.input.length > 15 ? inputStyle={border: '3px solid red'}: inputStyle }
```

This code means that if the character is more than 15 entered in the input field, then our input field's border will be red and the length of the border will be 3px.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way I got it done in a small React Bootstrap project:

```js
<Badge bg={`${todo.completed === true ? 'success' : 'danger'}`}>
  {todo.completed === true ? 'Completed' : 'Not Completed'}
</Badge>
```

Of course `success` and `danger` can be any color since they're bootstrap colors.