# Reactjsx set style depending on JSON-Value

Tags: json, reactjs, styles

I am trying to write a SPA with React.

I get a JSON-Object from a webservice which validates the Inputfields.

Now I want so set the Style of the Inputfield depending on the answer of the Webservice.
At example the Style should be:

```
style={{borderColor: 'green',   boxShadow: '0 0 5px green',}}
```

when the JSONValue is 0

```
<Input
    style = ???
    ...
/>
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "validate": {
        "isValidTest": 0
        ...
    }
}
```

---

edit: the JSON can have three different Values with three different Styles.

Comment: Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762351/correct-way-to-handle-conditional-styling-in-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of what you *could* do

**Example 1**

```
<Input
    style = 
        {{borderColor: obj.validate.isValidTest === 0 ? 'red':'green'
        boxShadow: `0 0 5px ${obj.validate.isValidTest === 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}`}}
    ...
/>
```

**What's happening here**

By utilizing the shorthand conditionals we can apply a borderColor & boxShadow to the style depending on the value of `isValidTest` within `obj` (which will be replaced by the name of your object)(!!)

Have a look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3m8zk4ko0) to see what is happening here

**NOTE**
Ofcourse, this could be separated from the inline `style` attribute by setting a `className` depending on the outcome of `isValidTest` or by applying a different style constant to it depending on the same conditional

**Example 2**

```
const errorStyles = {
  borderColor: 'red',
  boxShadow: '0 0 5px red'
}
const validStyles = {
  borderColor: 'green',
  boxShadow: '0 0 5px green'
}

<Input
    style={ obj.validate.isValidTest === 0 ? errorStyles : validStyles }
/>
```

Again, in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3m8zk4ko0) both examples are shown in the same file, on the same page.

You could also have a look at [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35762586/3666810) for more examples and information

**EDIT**

To account for more than two values in `isValidTest` you could go at it like so:

```
const errorStyles = {
  borderColor: 'red',
  boxShadow: '0 0 5px red'
}
const validStyles = {
  borderColor: 'green',
  boxShadow: '0 0 5px green'
}
const error2Styles = {
  borderColor: 'magenta',
  boxShadow: '0 0 5px magenta'
}
const valid2Styles = {
  borderColor: 'yellow',
  boxShadow: '0 0 5px yellow'
}


isValid = (valid) => {
    switch(valid) {
      case -1:
        return errorStyles
        break;
      case 0:
        return error2Styles
        break;
      case 1:
        return validStyles
        break;
      case 2:
        return valid2Styles
        break;
   }
}


<Input
    style={this.isValid(obj.validate.isValidTest)}
/>
```

**What happens in the above example**

As seen above the `style` attribute refers to `this.isValid` which in turn return a `const` containing the styles, supplied to this function is the `isValidTest` property from your `obj.validate`.

I have updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3m8zk4ko0) to include the above example

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the fast Help!!!

Can you show me how i can make this if i have three or more posible Values in JSON with diffrent Style's?

Comment: What would be the three possible values? is that `isValidTest` being able to be like `0` `1` or `2`? or would that mean there are multiple keys? @FlorianWidder

Comment: the Values can be  `-1`,  `0`,  `1` and `2`. Every time just one Value / Style per Input. @Simplicity

Comment: @FlorianWidder Happy to help!