# conditional styling in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React can I do something like this:

`style={ $post.type === "team_member" ? backgroundColor : "green"}`

How can I style according to a condition in React?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to handle conditional styling in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762351/correct-way-to-handle-conditional-styling-in-react)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, and it's close to what you already have;

```
style={{backgroundColor: $post.type === "team_member" ? 'green': 'not_a_team_member'}}
```

The `style` attribute expects an object, hence the double `{}`, you're only assigning the value of `backgroundColor` conditionally, so the conditional is the value of the key `backgroundColor` in the object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! After removing the $ symbol, it is working like charm! So, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```html
<div style={{ visibility: this.state.post.type === 'team_member'? 'green': ''}}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<div style={ post.type === "team_member" ? {backgroundColor : "green" }: '' }}></div>
```