# Can I add optional attributes to an element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, conditional-operator

Currently, in my React app I have this,

```
<input style={{ borderColor: valid ? null : "red", boxShadow: valid ? null : "rgb(2, 0, 0)"}} />
```

If I have more styling to do, it doesn't make sense checking the same condition again and again right? I wish to make the entire **style** attribute optional; something like this,

```
<input valid ? null : style={{ borderColor: "red", boxShadow: "rgb(2, 0, 0)"}} />
```

But I know that's not the right syntax. Isn't there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the logic into the style attribute and pass a neutral element for it in case of valid (or extract it into a variable).
I think this should do the trick:

```
<input style={valid ? {} : { borderColor: "red", boxShadow: "rgb(2, 0, 0)"}} />
```

Comment: Yeah. This works the best for me, without having to create any extra variables and add any packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use className to add style classes conditionally.You can use the classnames package as answered to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762351/correct-way-to-handle-conditional-styling-in-react)

Comment: Yeah, it does work. I just didn't want to get a new package. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a variable:

```js
const inputStyle = !valid ? {
  borderColor: "red",
  boxShadow: "rgb(2, 0, 0)"
} : {};

<input style={inputStyle}/>
```

It is the same that you currently have but you can add new properties as you wish into the variable without increasing the amount of comparisons in the `input` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your styles as an object in the render method, then assign it optionally as prop to the component using [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operators.

```
const styles = {
    borderColor: "red",
    boxShadow: "rgb(2, 0, 0)",
    // etc...
};

return (
    <input { ...(valid ? { styles } : {}) } />
);
```