# How to change a style of an element in React.js in onClick function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, if-statement

I am trying to change the color of list elements in my conditional rendering in react.js.

```js
onClick={exist ? () => {this.handleClick(); this.props.updateSummary(store_id)} : null }
```

I want to have `style="color :#E8E8E8"` and not :null. It seems like I can not use inline styling in onClick function while doing conditional rendering. Any ideas how to do it?
Thank you

```js
<ul>
   {this.props.stores.map(({exist, store_id}) => (
      <li className ="storeIdList" onClick={exist ? () => {this.handleClick(); this.props.updateSummary(store_id)} : null }>Store Id: {store_id}</li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Just... where is the styling here? Nothing about a `className` or a `style` attribute...

Comment: You <li> has storeIdList class. You want `style="color :#E8E8E8"` if exist is true?

Comment: @PankajShukla if exists I want `this.handleClick(); this.props.updateSummary(store_id)` this functions to run, if not : then change the style. Thank you

Comment: @sjahan, I want to add style in the place of :null and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to handle conditional styling in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762351/correct-way-to-handle-conditional-styling-in-react) You must use `className` or at least `style` you can't do this in `onClick`. `onClick` will trigger a change in, let's say, your `state` and this state will be used to pick a CSS class or a style value.

Comment: @sjahan, thank you. The problem is, if I do `onClick={exist ? () => {this.handleClick(); this.props.updateSummary(store_id)} : style={color:"something"}` it gives me error: assignment to undeclared variable style. Same with className.

Comment: You can handle the style change in the onclick handler. You cannot specify style change as style=something as onClick's function definition. style is an attribute of the element and if you say style=something on onClick outside the handler definition, it doesn't know what to do. That is why it is throwing error. You can check the solution here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-cs31e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code to have style like this:

```
<li
        style={!exist ? { color: "#E8E8E8" } : { color: "blue" }}>
        
</li>
```

Here it will take care of the case where you want the color to be changed to what you mentioned. When the item does exist then you can change the part where it is right now making the color blue as in `{ color: "blue" }`.

Take a look at this link for complete example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-silence-57isz?file=/src/App.js

What this means is that you have to provide all the properties as an object in the part after `:`.
In other words copy the properties defined in class `storeIdList` in the else part of the conditional expression.

Note: You cannot do what you want in `onClick` handler as that is for click handler callback and `NOT` to change the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Create two Css classes, and with your ternary put the right class