# How to remove style attribute added with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using a devExpress table with some custom requirements.

(UPDATE)
Took a break from this for a day and went back and did it properly using React Styling! Thanks for suggestions

[image: SCREENSHOT]

In the screenshot I have certain cells disabled. However the user wants all cells to look disabled other that the row selected.

Using this

```
   window
  .$("td")
  .not(document.getElementById(this.state.selection[0]))
  .not(document.getElementsByClassName(this.state.selection[0]))
  .not("td:first-child")
  .not(window.$("td:contains('iPlay')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('iLOE')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('iInvest')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('SPACER')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('$MM')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('$/BOE')"))
  .attr("style", "color:#868a8f");
window
  .$("td > div > div > div > input")
  .not(document.getElementsByClassName(this.state.selection[0]))
  .attr("style", "color:#868a8f");
```

I managed to achieve my desired result on page load
[image: SCREENSHOT2]

My problem is when I select a new row I cannot remove that color I applied before when it was not selected. I am trying to use "has" to find the selected row and change the color back to inherit or completely remove the style attribute.

```
    window
  .$("td")
  .has(document.getElementById(this.state.selection[0]))
  .has(document.getElementsByClassName(this.state.selection[0]))
  .not("td:first-child")
  .not(window.$("td:contains('iPlay')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('iLOE')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('iInvest')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('SPACER')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('$MM')"))
  .not(window.$("td:contains('$/BOE')"))
  .attr("style", "color:inherit");
window
  .$("td > div > div > div > input")
  .has(document.getElementsByClassName(this.state.selection[0]))
  .attr("style", "color:inherit");
```

If it helps I do have the ids of the rows that are NOT selected.
I tried to do something with that but did not have any luck

```
  const otherRows = ExpensesUtils.ROW_PROPS.filter(x => x !== this.state.selection[0]);
for (let i = 0; i < otherRows.length; i += 1) {
  window
  .$("td")
  .has(document.getElementById(otherRows[i]))
  .has(document.getElementsByClassName(otherRows[i]))
  .attr("style", "color:inherit");
  window
  .$("td > div > div > div > input")
  .has(document.getElementById(otherRows[i]))
  .has(document.getElementsByClassName(otherRows[i]))
  .attr("style", "color:inherit");
}
```

link to HTML
[Table HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/texas697/j4anvqhw/)

this.state.selection[0] is the selected rowId from the list below

I have applied the the rowIds to classes in the nested components. I could not figure out another way to access them.

```
  const ROW_PROPS = [
  "leaseAndWellExpense",
  "leaseAndWellExpenseBoe",
  "iloeLeaseAndWellExpense",
  "iloeLeaseAndWellExpenseBoe",
  "gnaLeaseAndWell",
  "gnaLeaseAndWellBoe",
  "transportation",
  "transportationBoe",
  "divisionGnA",
  "divisionGnABoe",
  "gatheringProcessing",
  "gatheringProcessingBoe",
  "hqGnA",
  "hqGnABoe",
  "interestExpense",
  "interestExpenseBoe",
  "netProdBoe",
  "leaseImpairments",
  "leaseImpairmentsBoe",
  "ddaProducing",
  "ddaProducingBoe",
  "iInvestDdaProducing",
  "iInvestDdaProducingBoe",
  "ddaGatheringProcessing",
  "ddaGatheringProcessingBoe",
  "iInvestDdaGatheringProcessing",
  "iInvestDdaGatheringProcessingBoe",
  "marketingCosts",
  "otherIncomeExpense",
  "otherIncomeExpenseBoe",
  "otherRevenue",
  "incomeTaxProvision",
  "incomeTaxProvisionBoe",
  "severanceTaxes",
  "severanceTaxesPercent",
  "currentTaxes",
  "currentTaxesRate",
  "netWellHeadRevenue",
];
```

Comment: Can you please add (part) of the HTML, so we know what to work with. See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is horrific JS. Why prefix window on $ ? Why mix DOM and jQuery? I cannot even guess what `.has(document.getElementById(this.state.selection[0]))` is supposed to do? Does the td contain an element wifh ID = this.state.selection[0] ??? That is the same as `$('#'+this.state.selection[0])` and then we can filter stuff instead of using not contains. If I only knew what `this.state.selection[0]` actually does

Comment: ALl of those selectors.... yikes, there probably is a lot better way to write that code.

Comment: @epascarello yes I am not familiar with jquery and I have a deadline!

Comment: ill add some more code asap

Comment: You should just create a style sheet rule in the CSS and add a class. It is a lot easier to remove a class.

Comment: `const arr = ['iPlay','iLOE','iInvest','SPACER','$MM','$/BOE']
$("td").filter(function() { return !arr.includes(this.text) }).toggleClass("green",someBoolean)`

Comment: updated post with link to HTML and some more explanation.

Comment: What's this supposed to mean? `window.$("td")`. And a lot of other stuff in this code. You really need to re-think and simplify it. As you've decided to use jQuery, do so for everything. Don't mix it up with vanilla JS.

Comment: Are you using any other framework, like ReactJS? It looks like there's something similar to it going on...

Comment: @melancia yes, react. I dont know what im doing here. thats why i need help

Comment: I wouldn't really mix ReactJS and jQuery. Their approach to coding is very, very different.

Comment: Starting on this thread you might find your way around achieving your goal. Just scrap the whole jQuery approach: [Correct way to handle conditional styling in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762351/correct-way-to-handle-conditional-styling-in-react)

Comment: @texas697 you should create a minimal example with your React code using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) and then describe what exactly your problem is and what you want it to do. For example, *"I want all cells of the table to be disabled but allow the users to select rows and enable the selected cells"*.

Comment: went a different route without jquery. used react styling. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of doing this is by creating a CSS rule's stylesheet.

In that stylesheet, you should define **2 classes**.

Let's suppose 1 for your desired CSS rules and the other for the default/none rules.

I am just showing you the simplest version of doing this thing but with another aspect.

```js
$('#b1').on('click', function() {
  $('.c1').removeClass('c1');
  $(this).addClass('c2');
});
```

```css
.c1 {
  color: red;
}

.c2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="b1">Change</button>
<p class="c1">This is a Test Line.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is

```
 $('#idName').on('click', function()
{
    $('.className').removeClass('removeClassName');
    $(this).addClass('addClassName');
});
```

The code above means that when a button with the id of `IdName` is clicked, the element with className will be removing the class of `removeClassName`, and adding the class of `addClassName`.

For further clarification you can have a look at [Removing CSS Using JQuery Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way by which you can achieve it.
Instead of playing with style attribute, since it takes the highest specificity so somewhere it might create an issue.
Instead of that you can use `toggleClass`. First add your default styling to table, whenever you click any row you can make use of  toggle class
[Toggle Class Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass)

Example.

```
$("td > div > div > div").click(function(){
  $("input").toggleClass("main");
```

})