# React: Data within a map is appearing different even though the code is written the same way for both instances where used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Apologies if this is poorly written (first time posting here so feedback on how to better write posts welcome!)

I am using react map to iterate through lists of data.

```
                          {level1Folders.level2Folders.map(
                        (level2Folders, index) => {
                          return (
                            <li
                              id={level2Folders.folderLevel2Name}
                              key={level2Folders.folderLevel2Name + index}
                            >
                              <div
                                className="menu-item-folder-level-2"
                                onClick={() =>
                                  hideMenuItem(
                                    level2Folders.folderLevel2Name
                                  )
                                }
                              >
                                <FaIcons.FaCaretRight />
                                {level2Folders.folderLevel2Name}
                              </div>

                              <ul
                                className="manuals d-none"
                                id={level2Folders.folderLevel2Name}
                              >
                                {level2Folders.manuals.map(
                                  (manual, index) => {
                                    return (
                                      <li key={manual + index} id={manual}>
                                        <div
                                          onClick={() =>
                                            handleExplorerItemClick(manual)
                                          }
                                          className="menu-item-manual"
                                        >
                                          {manual}
                                        </div>
                                      </li>
                                    );
                                  }
                                )}
```

I have a method hideMenuItem(menuItemId) which will hide items based on their id's, so the idea is to set the id = to the name of the item, so when the parent item is clicked the child elements will be hidden.

```
  function hideMenuItem(menuItemId) {
console.log(menuItemId);
let x = document.getElementById(menuItemId);
if (x.classList.contains('d-block')) {
  x.classList.add('d-none');
  x.classList.remove('d-block');
} else {
  x.classList.add('d-block');
  x.classList.remove('d-none');

}
 }
```

I have 5 uses of this - level2Folders.folderLevel2Name, the only one that won't work is when trying to enter this as a parameter in hideMenuItem(menuItemId), the value here is returned as the index of the item.

Answer (score 0):

The point here is you want to toggle the item's child by using the element's `classlist`. It might be better if you change your approach and use react ways to achieve your goals. One of them is conditional styling where you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762351/correct-way-to-handle-conditional-styling-in-react) for the details.

For your case, let me show you one of many approach which using state in show and hide elements. Try absorp the concept and implement it at yours.

First, the data  should have `name` which is the name of folder, `showSubFolders` which is property that will keep the boolean value, and `subFolders` that contains the sub folders details.

```
const folderData = [
  {
    name: "My Documents",
    showSubFolders: false,
    subFolders: [
      {
        name: "My Music",
        icon: faMusic
      },
      {
        name: "My Images",
        icon: faImage
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Then, set a folders state that will keep the folder's data in our component:

```
export default function OurComponent() {
  const [folders, setFolders] = useState(folderData);
  ...
}
```

Since we use `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={...} />`, so we can render the main folder icon by using conditional icon selection which depends on folder's `showSubFolders` property value:

```
return (
  ...
  <ul>
     {folders.map((folder, index) => {
        return (
           <li>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                 icon={folder.showSubFolders ? faFolderOpen : faFolder}
              />
           </li>
           ...
        )
      })}
   </ul>
   ...
)
```

The next is toggle subFolders section by creating a `toggleFolder` method that use `useCallback` hooks and depends on folders state. We `negate` the value of `showSubFolders` property if the folder name equal to the argument name supplied.

```
const toggleFolder = useCallback(
   (name) => {
      const toggledFolders = folders.map((folder) => {
        if (folder.name === name) {
          folder.showSubFolders = !folder.showSubFolders;
        }
        return folder;
      });
      setFolders(toggledFolders);
   },
   [folders]
);
```

And we can call the `toggleFolder` method from our list item as follow:

```
   return (
      ...
      {folders.map((folder, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
               <span onClick={() => toggleFolder(folder.name)}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                     icon={folder.showSubFolders ? faFolderOpen : faFolder}
                  />
                  {folder.name}
               </span>
               ...
            </li>
            ...
          )
      })}
      ...
   )
```

And when the `folders` state change, the component will re-render and we can use conditional render technique `{folder.showSubFolders && ( ... )` here:

```
   <li>
     ...
       {folder.showSubFolders && (
         <ul>
           {folder.subFolders.map((subFolder, index) => {
             return (
               <li key={index}>
                 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={subFolder.icon} />
                 {subFolder.name}
               </li>
             );
           })}
         </ul>
      )}
   </li>
```

Of course, this is not the only way to achieve your goal, but it is more `React Way` in doing so.

And lastly, this is the final code:

[image: Edit compassionate-water-08xdv0]

Comment: This is perfect - all working thank you!